# twitter count always returns 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter

i am making custom twitter button and counter. the counter is always returning 0.

here is the code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=Aoraxous" target="_blank"
  data-url="http://www.twitter.com/aoraxous"
  data-via="AORAXOUS"
  data-text=""
  data-count="horizontal">Tweet                           
</a>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery.getJSON(
    'ht' + 'tp://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=Aoraxous/&callback=?',
    function (data) {

        alert(data.count);
    }
);
```

any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's returning zero count because you are not permitted to request from urls.api.twitter.com -- it's not a public API. See this thread [Counting does not seem to work with other URL shortening services](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6680) and [Is http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json? a valid way to get the tweet count for a URL?](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5653)